# On the evaluation of the integral $\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

The integral $\displaystyle \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x^2+1}\,dx$ can be evaluated with the standard technic of sub $u=\tan \theta$. However, in the book says evaluate the integral without trigonometric substitution.

I can't find a way. I applied the sub $u=1-x$ and it got a little messie.
I also tried to approach it geometrically, but again I had a problem because the graph is not a common shape thus saying that the integral is equal to the area of that shape.

For example if I had the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \sqrt{1-x^2}\,dx$ then this equal to aread of the quadrateral etc. In the case of the other integral I don't see something like this.

If someone could give me a hint,that would be nice!!

Comment: From the complex point of view this is cheating, but one could use the hyperbolic substitution $x = \sinh t$, $dx = \cosh t \,dt$.

Comment: Again, it's like a trigonometric sub!

Comment: If it would be useful to you, I can write up my comment as a full answer, but if you find it unsatisfying I won't.

Comment: Well, hyperbolic functions aren't **exactly** trigonometric ones ... I'd go with $\;x=\sinh u\;$

Comment: I am flabbergasted: at least two answers avoid carefully trigonometric lines, as requested, and rely only on primitives of rational functions, but the OP accepts the answer using (hyperbolic) trigonometric lines.

Comment: Better now: the newly accepted answer only requires to know a primitive of $1/\sqrt{x^2+1}$. Since other ways avoid this, one can still argue, but...

Comment: Yeah.. I accepted the other answer... which is more high-school like. I apologize for turning down the other. The primitive of the latter is known to me.. and I have done it without trig subs... 

Thank you all for the quick replies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I=\int\sqrt{x^2+1}dx=x\sqrt{x^2+1}-\int x \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}2xdx=x\sqrt{x^2+1}-\int \frac{x^2-1+1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dx=x\sqrt{x^2+1}-\int\sqrt{x^2+1}dx-\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}dt=x\sqrt{x^2+1}-I-\ln|x+\sqrt{x^2+1}|,$$so$$I=\frac{1}{2}\left(x\sqrt{x^2+1}-\ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})\right)+C.$$

Comment: The absolute value is not necessary in the final formula.

Answer (score 12):

**Hint.** Substitute: $\sqrt{x^2+1}=x+t$. This transforms your algebraic integral into a purely rational one:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}-1}\frac{t+\frac{1}{t}}{2}\cdot\frac{(-1)(t^2+1)}{2t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you.. that is also a nice way of computing it.

Comment: @Did And yet the wonderful magic of Euler substitutions continues to not be taught in basic courses. This vexes me. >:(

Answer (score 5):

To avoid trigonometric substitutions, one can use the change of variable $$t=\sqrt{1+\frac1{x^2}},$$ which leads to $$t\geqslant\sqrt2,\qquad\sqrt{1+x^2}=xt,\qquad x^2=\frac1{t^2-1},\qquad t\,\mathrm dt=\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^3},$$ hence $$\int_0^1\sqrt{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx=\int_{\sqrt2}^\infty(tx)(x^3t\,\mathrm dt)=\int_{\sqrt2}^\infty\frac{t^2}{(t^2-1)^2}\,\mathrm dt.$$
As a rational function of $t$, the function in the last integral has an explicit primitive, hence we are done.

Comment: Did, isn't it going to be $t dt= -\frac{dx}{x^3}$??? How did you get +?

Comment: @TheArtist By considering the integral from $\sqrt2$ to $\infty$, not the other way round (as one always does).

Comment: Oh :) Thank you Did :)

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Set $x=\sinh u$ then
$$\int_0^1\sqrt{1+x^2}dx=\int_{0}^{\ln(1+\sqrt 2)}\sqrt{1+\sinh^2(u)}\cosh(u)du=\int_0^{\ln(1+\sqrt 2)}\cosh^2(u)du$$
now integrate by part with $a(u)=\cosh u$ and $b'(u)=\cosh(u)$

Comment: did you read the comments below the question?

Comment: First of all thank you for the quick replies. It is just that in high school students aren't though anything of hyperbolical function , inverse functions. Therefore these kind of subs are out of question.

Comment: @Tolaso, yet h.s. students are usually taught exponential functions, so don't talk of hyperbolic functions but of exponential ones, and the substitution now is $\;u=\frac12\left(e^u-e^{-u}\right) $ ...what about this one?

Comment: Well this makes sense... thus avoiding that.. Anyway,I found another one solution.. applying parts.. and gets to the integral $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{dt}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$. The latter I have evaluated it without trig sub..

Thank you all...

Comment: @Tolaso I have applied parts to get a different integral.

Comment: ??!! @Tolaso How did you evaluate that integral without trigonomeric and/or hyperbolic functions, please??

Comment: By cheating, actually. I applied the inverse procedure of differentiating the $\ln \left(x+\sqrt{x^2+1} \right) $.

Comment: @VarunIyer May I have a starting point of your try?

Comment: @Tolaso By that reasoning, one might as well accept simply writing down the known antiderivative and observing that its derivative is the integral in question. In fact, the function you differentiate is $\arsinh x$ itself, so this method by no means avoids hyperbolic trig functions either...